# How do I 'find' a line of an array from a value?

Tags: c++

I'm not really sure how I'd go about this. I have an array with several values in each line. For instance, there's a 'name' value, an 'id' value, and some other values. I'm reading another text file, that has a number, which I want to then 'find' the array and edit it. I'm not sure if I'm explaining it right, but let's say for example, the new text file says.

```
    2000 -1.6
```

I would want to then find the 'array' that has an ID value of '`2000'`. Let's say that `Array[3]` (using Array as an example name of my array) has the ID value of `2000`. How would I make the program 'know' that `Array[3]` has the same value? I want to make it look for the line that has the same ID as the line from the text file.

Additionally, is there a way to read that `'-1.6'` as an integer of `1.6`, but as a negative number without specifically singling it out? I'm sorry if my explanation is weird, but I can't think of any other way to say it.

EDIT: This is the code I have right now. This is just one problem in the program that I'm not sure how to go about. The function "getdata2" is where I would do this. I want that function to read the text file (which I know how to do) which has two values in each line; a 4 digit number (the ID), and a numerical value like "-1.6". I want to find the line of the array that has an ID that matches the one in the A/B/C.txt file, and edit its 'weight' value with the numerical value from the A/B/C.txt file. So an example of what I want to do is this. I execute my program. The third line has an ID value of '2000', and a weight value of '52'. After I read all the lines from peeps.txt (the first text file used in the function getdata), I would execute function getdata2, which would read data from A/B/C.txt. If the first line of text in that file reads "2000 -1.6", I would want it to 'find' the part of the array with the ID value of 2000 (in this case Person[3]), and then modify its weight value by subtracting 1.6 from it, changing it to 50.4. I'm not sure how to go about 'finding' it however.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct person
{
string firstname;
int id;
double height;
double weight;
double bmi;
double change;
};
void getdata (person *array, person *ptr);
void printData (person *array, person *ptr);
void calculateBMI (person *array, person*ptr);
void getdata2 (person *array, person *ptr);
int main()
{
person array[13];
 person *ptr;
ptr = &array[0];
getdata(array, ptr);
calculateBMI(array, ptr);
printData(array, ptr);




}

void getdata (person *array, person *ptr)
{

ifstream inData;
inData.open("peeps.txt");
while(!inData.eof())
{
    for(ptr = &array[0]; ptr < &array[13];ptr++)
{
inData >> ptr->firstname >> ptr->id
>> ptr->height >> ptr->weight;

}
}
}
void printData (person *array, person *ptr)
{
cout << "Name" << "     ID" << "     Height"
<< "     Weight   " << "BMI" << endl;
for(ptr = &array[0]; ptr < &array[13];ptr++)
{
cout << ptr->firstname << "   "<< ptr->id
<< "   "<< ptr->height << "       "<< ptr->weight <<
"      "<< ptr->bmi << endl;
}
}
void calculateBMI (person *array, person*ptr)
{
for(ptr = &array[0]; ptr < &array[13];ptr++)
{
    ptr-> bmi = 703*(ptr->weight/((ptr->height)*(ptr->height)));
}
}
void getdata2 (person *array, person *ptr)
{
ifstream inData;
string filename;
int size;
cout << "Select from file 'A', 'B', or 'C'" << endl;
cin >> filename;
if (filename == "a" || filename == "A")
{
    inData.open("A.txt");
    cout << "Opening A.txt..." << endl;
    size = 17;
}
if (filename == "b" || filename == "B")
{
    inData.open("B.txt");
    cout << "Opening B.txt..." << endl;
    size = 9;
}
if (filename == "c" || filename == "C")
{
    inData.open("C.txt");
    cout << "Opening C.txt..." << endl;
    size = 12;
}
else
{
cout << "You have entered an incorrect filename." << endl;
}
while (size > 0)
{

    size--;
}


}
```

Comment: can you be a little more clear about what types you're working with? are you dealing with a vector<string> ?

Comment: also what do you mean by "several values in each line"?

Comment: This is not a reasonable question... you should try to code some of this yourself and ask specific questions where you're stuck.  As is, there's no way we can know if you know how to open the file, parse the values, use a vector, a for loop etc. - so we've no idea how much detail to provide.

Comment: I tried really hard to understand your question but I still don't understand.

Comment: In his past questions, a "line" meant a "std::string initialized from a line in a text file". Josh, please put more effort into *showing* and *describing* your code.  If someone has a minute to help you, they'll spend that whole minute trying to understand you.

Comment: The word "line" doesn't fit with my knowledge of arrays. Do you mean you are searching for a specific *element* in the array or are you searching for a *row* in a 2D array? Also, how do you store both a name and an id in the same array? They are two different types (typically a `string` and an `int`). You cannot mix types in an array. Maybe you need to create a class which stores the related values together in an object?

Comment: After reading your question a little more carefully, it looks like you have several issues in one question. I suggest you figure out how to separate them out and ask separate questions for each one. For example, if you need help with reading the file in the first place, you might want to focus on that in a separate question.

Comment: If you just paste your entire program no one's going to want to read it. Try narrowing down your question to something specific, with a specific piece of code. That's the best way to get a good answer on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

std::find_if will do what you want, if paired up with a functor (in this case, isTarget).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct X { int id; int val; };

class isTarget {
public:
    isTarget(int target): target_(target) {}
    bool operator() (X &item) { return item.id == target_; }
private:
    int target_;
};

int main()
{
    X x[] = { {1000, 1}, {2000, 2}, {3000, 3}, {4000, 4} };
    X* ele = std::find_if(x, x+4, isTarget(3000));  // this does the work
    std::cout << ele->val;

    return 0;
}
```